# "Need more values to unpack" warning in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, warnings

Just a curious warning, it doesn't seem to cause any issues so far, but it's a strong warning and I'd like to be rid of it.

So this line in my code has been flagged with this problem:

```
ultrafines_min, ultrafines_max = self.ultra_fines_limits
```

The attribute `self.ultra_fines_limits` is declared earlier in the code and comes from a lookup in another class:

```
self.ultra_fines_limits = UltraFinesLimits.values()
```

Finally, this is the class declaration for UltraFinesLimits:

```
class UltraFinesLimits(enum.Enum):

    low_limit = 0
    top_limit = 35

    @classmethod
    def values(cls) -> Tuple[int]:
        return tuple(map(lambda c: c.value, [*cls]))
```

As you can see, `values()` method is meant to return a tuple, which it certainly does:

```
(0, 35)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

So I'm confused as to why I get the warning. Is it because I can potentially have more than two values in the tuple?

Comment: Just for curiosity, why do you use "Pycharm" in the title? Recently we have so many such questions, so: there is a tutorial or a online curse which makes people to think PyCharm is a programming language, or that uses too much PyCharm instead of Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I would say yes - that's why you're getting the warning.

A tuple in Python is an n-tuple, not strictly a 2-tuple.
(see https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences)

I would bet that this would clear the warning:

```
ultrafines_min, ultrafines_max, _ = self.ultra_fines_limits
```

But more usefully, you might want to take a look at the value() function and see if there is a better way of packaging your min & max values.
Perhaps more explicit is better in this case?

```
@classmethod
def values(cls) -> Tuple[int]:
    return cls.low_limit, cls.top_limit
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think I'll do as you suggested and change the `values()` method.